# perl pattern matching from end of line

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I am trying to strip off comments at the end of every line that I encounter. However, I am interested to preserve the line if it is commented at the very beginning in addition to the end.

For example:

```
output port_a; // comments remove this port
```

If I use this regex `$line =~ s/\/{2,}.*?$//;`, the comments are removed correctly yielding only the pattern that I want to use for further processing, which is:

```
output port_a;
```

However, it can happen that a line can be commented at the beginning:

```
// output port_a; // comments remove this port
```

In this case, I want to preserve the comment at the beginning of line, but remove the comment at the end of the line.

```
// output port_a;
```

Using the same regex `$line =~ s/\/{2,}.*?$//;` removes everything!

I have tried using `s/\/{2,}[^\/]+$//g` but this does not strip off comment that has a slash in it, which is incorrect:

```
// output port_a; // comments read/write
```

Comment: Use a tempered dot, `s/\/{2,}(?:(?!\/\/).)*?$//;`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNt6TL/2/)

Comment: That demo website is super cool! Thanks for the information

Comment: Yes, you can use it to play around and figure out the right pattern. That and a few more: http://regexr.com/, https://regexper.com/, https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow an optional `/` at the beginning, remove a trailing comment if there

```
s|^\s*/?.+?\K//.*||g;
```

The `+` quantifier is needed instead of a `*` so to not match lines with a sole comment.

The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) is a form of [lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), a *zero-width assertion* that the pattern that precedes it is indeed there  (it doesn't consume anything). It also discards all matches prior to it, so we don't have to capture them and put them back in. This also allows `\K` to handle variable length patterns.

Test with shown examples

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @tests = (
    'output port_a; // comments remove this port',
    '// output port_a; // comments remove this port',
    '// output port_a; // comments read/write'
);

for (@tests)
{ 
    s|^\s*/?.+?\K//.*||gx;
    say;
}
```

output

```
output port_a; 
// output port_a;
// output port_a;
```

Comment: what is the \K for?

Comment: @JonJ it's a lookbehind. I am on a cell phone now, will add a note about it when I get back to the computer.

Comment: @JonJ  Added a brief explanation of `\K`, see the linked pages for more.

Answer (score 0):

Following works, using `@` as regex delimiter instead of `/` to avoid backslashes before `/` and be clearer

```
s@//([^/]|/([^/]|$))*$@@
```

How it works.
After `//` : we can find

- either `[^/]` (any character except `/`)
- either `/` followed by `[^/]` or `$` end of line anchor

Answer (score 0):

Use a tempered dot,

```
$line =~ s/\/{2,}(?:(?!\/\/).)*?$//;
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lNt6TL/2/)

Regex: `\/{2,}(?:(?!\/\/).)*?$`

- `\/{2,}` matches 2 or more slashes (representing start of comment)
- `(?:(?!\/\/).)*?` represents a tempered dot (which means any character except one that is preceeded by `//`). This is specified using a negative lookahead `(?!\/\/)`.
- `$` ending anchor

Hope this helps!

Comment: It certainly does!

Answer (score 0):

This removes the *last* comment on the line. It is much clearer

```
s|.*\K//.*||
```

Here's a demonstration program

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {

    print "$.\n";

    print;

    s|.*\K//.*||;
    print;

    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
output port_a; // comments remove this port
output port_a;
// output port_a; // comments remove this port
// output port_a;
```

#### output

```
1
output port_a; // comments remove this port
output port_a; 

2
output port_a;
output port_a;

3
// output port_a; // comments remove this port
// output port_a; 

4
// output port_a;
```

Comment: Never knew data can be coded in like that ... \__DATA__